# How to sort a Material UI DataGrid column programatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

Hello I have a DataGrid with a column that has a custom header. This header is a Select.
What I want to do is every time the user selects an option the column should be sorted desc.
The renderHeader looks like this

```
renderHeader: (params) => {
    return <CategoryPickerHeader value={category} handleChange={setCategory} />;
  },
```

I know the DataGrid api has a couple methods for sorting (https://v4.mui.com/api/data-grid/grid-api/#main-content) sortColumn() & applySorting()

But I haven't found any example of how to use those api methods.

Can someone provide an example or knows how to use the DataGrid api?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Visit this page, this has an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ugeb8?file=/demo.js

IMPORTANT : pass the arguments to property sortModel, is this answer

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { useDemoData } from '@mui/x-data-grid-generator';

export default function BasicSortingGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: 'Commodity',
    rowLength: 10,
    maxColumns: 6,
  });

  const [sortModel, setSortModel] = React.useState([
    {
      field: 'commodity',
      sort: 'asc',
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        {...data}
        sortModel={sortModel}
        onSortModelChange={(model) => setSortModel(model)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But thats not quite what I'm asking for. What I need to know is how to use the sorting methods from the DataGrid api, as I intend to override the default behavior

Comment: tell me what you want to do?

Comment: I want to know how to use the params.api.sortColumn(); method included in the api of the renderHeader method of the dataGrid columns. I want that because I want to auto sort descendingly every time the handleChange is triggered

Comment: check this out, maybe you can find something to help you:  https://material-ui-x.netlify.app/storybook/?path=/story/datagridpro-test-filter--with-new-operator

Comment: @WilliamMelo your storybook points to a 404 now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i added default sort with DataGrid component:

```
<DataGrid
  initialState={{
    sorting: {
      sortModel: [{ field: 'rating', sort: 'desc' }],
    },
  }}
/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).